# Could not get my Rails going. Command rails server does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My environment: Windows 10

```
PS D:\\dev-rails\\repo\\test6\> ruby -v
ruby 3.1.1p18 (2022-02-18 revision 53f5fc4236) \[x64-mingw-ucrt\]
PS D:\\dev-rails\\repo\\test6\> rails -v
Rails 7.0.2.3
PS D:\\dev-rails\\repo\\test6\> node -v
v16.14.2
PS D:\\dev-rails\\repo\\test6\> npm -v
8\.5.5
PS D:\\dev-rails\\repo\\test6\> yarn -v
1\.22.18
```

When I type in the repo: rails server

```
PS D:\\dev-rails\\repo\\test6\> rails server
PS D:\dev-rails\repo> rails new test7
       exist
   identical  README.md
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  .ruby-version
   identical  config.ru
   identical  .gitignore
   identical  .gitattributes
   identical  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:258:in ``': No such file or directory - git config init.defaultbranch (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:258:in `user_default_branch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:76:in `version_control'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:134:in `public_send'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:134:in `build'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:328:in `create_root_files'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command/base.rb:87:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/rails:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/bin/rails:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you edit your question? It'd be easier to read if you separate console print and comments. You can use the code editor for example or some other bloc separator.

Comment: Is git installed?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer to give some background.

To solve this, install `git`.

Rails tries to run `git init from "."` to initialize a repository in your current working directory.

Rails [reads](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2a98e28a31d3b9a720c4a9571c23b40433a035df/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L484)  the git default branch, see [this post on superuser.com about the default branch](https://superuser.com/questions/1419613/change-git-init-default-branch-name).

To configure the init.defaultBranch parameter in git > 2.28, you can run `git config --global init.defaultBranch main`.

Not sure why you would do it but you could skip this step by using these console options:
`-G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]`
`-p, [--pretend], [--no-pretend]`

See [Rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2b2e789cb714dab2d37db8c7449d1f229ea8257f/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/plugin/plugin_generator.rb#L69) and run `rails new --help` to learn more.